# Do neural networks work with high-dimensional small sample data?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, small-sample, high-dimensional

Are neural networks used for the classification of high-dimensional small sample data like gene microarray data, where the dimension may be on the order of 1000 features per sample with around 100 samples? Do they work well in this setting, and if not, then what kind of classifiers are usually used with this kind of data?

Comment: traditionally, Lasso and its derivatives tend to be popular for such data.

Comment: I did a Google Scholar search for `gene OR genetic "microarray data" "neural network"` and found almost 20,000 articles.

Comment: @Sycorax-OnStrike Thank you for the pointer. I was more so asking if neural networks can be used 'as is' for this kind of data or if special modifications to the data or network architecture would need to be made. I was thinking there may be a general expert agreement about this as in "neural networks over-fit high-dimensional, small sample data". I have never worked with neural networks.